# Combinations and Permutations. Number of integer solutions

Tags: permutations, combinations

```
Question: How many integer solutions of
```

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 17$

```
Satisfy:
```

$x_1 \ge 0 , x_2 \ge 1, x_3 \ge 2, x_4 \ge 3\text{ ?}$

Answer: C(11 + 4 -1, 4-1)

This is the answer the textbook has, can anyone explain how they got that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_2'=x_2-1$, $x_3'=x_3-2$, $x_4'=x_4-3$.  We may then rewrite your equation as $$x_1+(x_2'+1)+(x_3'+2)+(x_4'+3)\ge 17$$
which we may rewrite again as $$x_1+x_2'+x_3'+x_4'\ge 11$$
Only now $x_1, x_2', x_3',x_4'$ are arbitrary nonnegative integers.  These are [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions) of $11$ into $4$ parts, which are given by $${11+4-1\choose 4-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $17$ identical marbles.

Temporarily put $6$ of the marbles aside, leaving $11$.

Add $3$ identical dividers to the $11$ marbles.

These $14$ items can be arranged in $14!$ way.  Divide by $3!$ and $11!$, because the marbles and dividers are indistinguishable.  There are thus $$\frac{14!}{3!\cdot 11!}$$
different arrangements

Now put $1$ of the removed marbles after the first divider, $2$ after the second, and the last $3$ after the third divider.  The marble counts represent all the integer solutions to the original equation.